# poner subdominio en odoo

Tags: apache, odoo

Amigos buenos dias espero me puedan orientar más tengo un servidor en azure con apache y odoo 13 el servidor esta funcionando corectamente realice la instalacion de apache y un direcionamiento desde un subdominio hacia la ip y puse esta configuracion en apache2/site-available/000-default.conf

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerName erp.dominio.com
        ServerAlias erp.dominio.com
        ServerAdmin odoo@erp.dominio.com

        LogLevel warn
        ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/erp.dominio.com.error.log
        CustomLog /var/log/apache2/erp.dominio.com.access.log combined

        ProxyRequests Off
        ProxyPreserveHost On
        ProxyPass / http://localhost:8069/
        ProxyPassReverse / http://localhost:8069/
</VirtualHost>
```

con esto estoy redireccionando la pagina de inicio de apache hacia el servidor y funciona correctamente pero quiero que en la barra de direccion en mi servidor de odoo me aparesca el subdominio es decir:

[image: Quiero que donde esta la ip me muestre el subdomino]

como puedo realizarlo espero me arienten mas estoy enpezando en odoo gracias amigos les agradesco

Comment: Que subdominio quieres que te aparezca?

Comment: quiero que me aparesca el mismo de cuando apunto con la ip es decir este erp.dominio.com y no la ip

Comment: Solo te falta reescribir tus reglas, podrías usar esto al final del `ProxyPassReverse`:  `RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [END,NE,R=permanent]`

Comment: es decir delante del http://localhost:8069/ algo asi: ProxyPassReverse / http://localhost:8069/ RewriteEngine On RewriteRule ^ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [END,NE,R=permanent] o sin el localhost:8069 espero me aclares gracias amigo

Comment: agrégalo debajo de lo ultimo que haces, osea arriba del `</VirtualHost>`

Comment: es decir asi quedaria:
`ProxyPassReverse / http://localhost:8069/

        ProxyPassReverse: RewriteEngine On RewriteRule ^ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [END,NE,R=permanent]
</VirtualHost>`

Comment: No, así no. No cambies nada, solo agrega antes de cerrar el virtualhost lo que te dije

Comment: a ok voy a validarlo gracias ya te aviso

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/105741/discussion-between-synay-and-carlos-chavita).